# Is this possible in google charts or is there an alternitive or hack

Tags: charts, google-visualization

is it possible for this type of chart to be created by any means using the google charting api

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example can be achieved by using an alternative charting library called [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com). You can use the chart type "[range](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/range/)" and the [rules](http://www.zingchart.com/blog/2015/08/27/beginner-series-part-4-markers-labels-rules/) feature to set min and max color areas depending on a certain value range. The horizontal red and blue lines can be achieved by using the scale-x markers.

See the example below for how you would utilize ZingChart to achieve what you are looking for. I'm on the ZingChart team so feel free to reach out to us if you need any further help.

```js
var myConfig = {
  type:"range",
  backgroundColor : "white",
  scaleX:{
      maxItems:8,
      zooming:1,
  },
  scaleY:{
      minValue:"auto",
      markers : [
        {
          type : "line",
          range : [70],
          lineColor : "red"
        },
        {
          type : "line",
          range : [30],
          lineColor : "blue"
        }
      ]
  },
  "series":[
      {
          lineWidth:2,
          lineColor:"#8100a4",
          marker:{
            type:"none"
          },
          values : [[60,60],[70,70],[78,70],[75,70],[70,70],[50,50],[60,60],[60,60],[60,60],[34,34],[35,35],[35,35],[35,35],[30,30],[24,30],[26,30],[25,30],[28,30],[30,30],[32,32]],
          backgroundColor:"#1049c4",
          rules:[
            {
              rule:"%node-max-value < %node-min-value",
              backgroundColor:"#c00"
            }
          ],
          minLine:{
            lineColor:"#8100a4",
          },
          maxLine:{
            lineColor:"#8100a4"
          }
      }
  ]
};
 
zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 300, 
 width: 500 
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/2.1.4/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script> zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/2.1.4/modules/";</script></head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you
but i already have developed an extensive amount through the google charts api, and i rely on there range charts and the dashboard facilities.

seems like this type of charts aren't possible through google api
so thank you so much for the answer 
i will have to switch to this api. hope google had something like